# regexp (sed) suppress "no match" output

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm stuck on that and can't wrap my head around it: How can I tell sed to return the value found, and otherwise **shut up**?

It's really beyond me: Why would sed return the whole string if he found nothing? Do I have to run *another* test on the returned string to verify it?  I tried using "-n" from the (very short) man page but it effectively suppresses all output, including matched strings.

This is what I have now :

```
echo plop-02-plop | sed -e 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/'
```

which returns
`02` (and that is fine and dandy, thank you very much), but:

```
echo plop-02plop | sed -e 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/'
```

returns
`plop-02plop` (when it should return this = "" **nothing**! Dang, you found nothing so be quiet!
 For crying out loud !!)

I tried checking for a return value, but this failed  too ! Gasp !!

```
$ echo plop-02-plop | sed -e 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/' ; echo $?
02
0
$ echo plop-02plop | sed -e 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/' ; echo $?
plop-02plop
0
$
```

This last one I cannot even believe. Is `sed` really the tool I should be using? I want to extract a needle from a haystack, and I want a needle or *nothing*..?

Comment: As you have discovered, `sed` is doing as you request; it is a stream editor and prints its input to its output as modified by the script.  Your non-matching case didn't change the data, so what was echoed was your input - this is the correct behaviour for `sed`.  And the answer to suppressing output is to use `-n` and then add an explicit `p` when you want something printed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`sed` by default prints all lines.

What you want to do is:

```
/patt/!d;s//repl/
```

In other words, delete lines not matching your pattern, and for lines that do match, extract particular element from it, giving capturing group number for instance. In your case it will be:

```
sed -e '/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/!d;s//\2/'
```

You can also use `-n` option to suppress echoing all lines. Then line is printed only when you explicitly state it. In practice, scripts using `-n` are usually longer and more cumbersome to maintain. Here it will be:

```
sed -ne 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/p'
```

There is also `grep`, but your example shows why `sed` is sometimes better.

Comment: I'll be damned, it works. Thank you very much sir.
@sehe Thanks, I will check grep.

Comment: You can shorten the `-n` version to: `sed -ne 's/^.*\(.\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\1.*$/\2/p'` which is shorter than your version without `-n`.

Comment: @Jonathan You're absolutely right. In this particular case `-n` is shorter indeed. I should've written `-n` way as you suggested from the beginning, but it somehow slipped my mind. Pretty embarrassing. ;)

Comment: @Jonathan @przemoc And what would one do to get the opposite ? That is returning the string without the matched bit ?

Comment: @xaccrocheur Remove `!` in my boilerplate (and possibly `s///` command too; depends on whether you want to further modify it or not). For `-n` way it would be `/patt/!p`.

Comment: @xaccrocheur: `sed -ne 's/^\(.*\)\(.\)[0-9][0-9]\1\(.*\)$/\1\2\2\3/p'` - untested

Comment: @xaccrocheur I misread your question. @Jonathan seems almost right, but used wrong backreference in pattern (should be \2 instead of \1).

Comment: -ne ... /p is really convenient

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use `egrep -o`?

input.txt:

```
blooody
aaaa
bbbb
odor
qqqq
```

E.g.

```
sehe@meerkat:/tmp$ egrep -o o+ input.txt 
ooo
o
o
sehe@meerkat:/tmp$ egrep -no o+ input.txt 
1:ooo
4:o
4:o
```

Of course `egrep` will have slightly different (better?) regex syntax for advanced constructs (back-references, non-greedy operators). I'll let you do the translation, if you like the approach.